# need to know to what API should be used with setOnLoadCompleteListener

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I have a phone and tablet.

In my code, there is a thread for Autosound.

**For phone it looks like**

```
 void Thread(boolean b){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
            public void run() {                 
                while (!stopRequested) {
                    if(MainScreen.tgbutton.isChecked() == false) {  
                        mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool mSoundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                                mSoundPool.play(mSlovo, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                                }
                            });

                        stop(); 
                        } 
                    else {
                        stop();
                        }
                    }
                }           
            public void stop () {
                stopRequested = true;
                }
            }, 100);
    };
```

**Tablet so**

```
void Thread(boolean b){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
        public void run() {                 
            while (!stopRequested) {
                if(MainScreen.tgbutton.isChecked() == false) {                  
                    mSoundPool.play(mSlovo, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                    stop(); 
                    } 
                else {
                    stop();
                    }
                }
            }           
        public void stop () {
            stopRequested = true;
            }
        }, 100);
};
```

**I want to combine these two threads into one, but need to know to what API should be used with setOnLoadCompleteListener.**

UPD: on the tablet works without the listener, if you add a listener that the sound is not working on the tablet